# Minimal number of phone connections to ensure a sufficient number of direct lines

Tags: self-study

A set of telephone connections should be installed in order to connect the cities $A$ and $B$. City $A$ has $2000$ phones.
Assuming that each user in city $A$ needs a telephone connection to city $B$ for $2$ minutes on average during the $10$ working hours and that these calls are completely random, what is the minimal number $M$ of telephone connections to city $B$ in order to ensure, that not more than $1$% of the calls from city $A$ to city $B$ do not get a direct line?

I am supposed to assume a Gaussian distribution.

All I found is, that the mean of the Gaussian should be $2000\times\frac{2}{60}=6.6667$ connections, based on the given time intervals. - $6\frac{2}{3}$ people are expected to have a call at any given moment in  the specified time interval.

How do I proceed from here? - How do I obtain a variance in order to get the 99% confidence interval, necessary to solve the problem.

Furthermore, how do I deal with the, in reality, impossible situations where I have less than 0 or more than 2000 calls at any given moment? Do I just renormalize the clamped section so the integral over it gives 1 or do I ignore those technically impossible cases, or how to deal with them?

Comment: It would seem to me that you are missing information. The Gaussian distribution has two parameters, mean and standard p deviation. You have only provided the mean.

Comment: The mean is what I already calculated. that's exactly the point. How would I get a good assumption for the variance? If I have that, it should be pretty easy to get to the 99% confidence interval.

Comment: @Russel this is all the information I have. - it's about optimizing the number of direct lines so you don't need 2000 cables - one per telephone - as worst case.

Comment: As an aside, the question is also worded poorly. Just because city A has 2000 phones it does not logically follow that there are 2000 users.

Comment: I pretty much used the wording in which the problem got stated to me.

Comment: Does "completely random" mean uniform?

Comment: It means, any one person may choose any 2-minute-intervall of the 10 hours. (And per assumption, every phone has one user and is used statistically exactly once.)

Comment: This question lacks crucial information needed for its solution. Due to the randomness, you *cannot* ensure that no more than 1% of the calls fail until you construct $0.99\times 2000 = 1980$ lines. Instead you have to ask about reducing the *probability* that $1$% of the calls will fail during some *specified period*.  Also, to what does the assumed "Gaussian distribution" refer? Call lengths? Numbers of calls per minute?

Comment: @whuber the gaussian distribution refers to an approximation of the number of currently occupied connections with the expected value being $6\frac{2}{3}$ (as calculated above) and the variance being what I'm trying to find.

Comment: Have you learned about the Binomial distribution? If so, you can model the number of connections at any moment as a Binomial$(2000, 2/(60\times 10))$ distribution. Its expectation is, as you say, $20/3\approx 6.67$ and its variance is $299/45\approx 6.65$. Although a Normal (Gaussian) approximation tends to be bad, the two distribution functions (seemingly accidentally) draw close near the $90$th to $98$th percentiles, which is near your values of interest.  Just be careful in describing and interpreting the result: you are *not* computing a confidence interval here.

Comment: @whuber that's a good call. It also fits very well with the Poisson distribution as suggested by StasK: The mean and variance are almost identical. In case of the poisson distribution, they would be exactly identical. If nobody has any other ideas by the time I have to work this out, I'll just use those two solutions. Approximating either with a Gaussian, I get 12.66 or 12.67 as necessary number, which both agree with the 13 of the direct poisson distribution, so at least, the result shouldn't be far off what's meant to be found. Sadly I don't have any solutions to verify against...

Comment: For verification, run a simulation :-).

Comment: @whuber ok, your idea with approximating it by a binomial distribution officially was the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know that. Please take "correct" with a big grain of salt--I would instead read that word as "intended." There is no unique best solution, due to the many assumptions that need to be made in order to derive any solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>In that case, I think the best you can do is to assume a standard deviation of 1 (as that is the 'default').  However it is unclear whether you should assume that is the standard deviation of the calls (in which case the units are clearly minutes) or the standard deviation of total time of connection between City A and City B.</s>

If it is the former, then there is a practical problem because a non-trivial amount of the distribution would include calls with negative time.  Ignoring the problem of stochastic time selection and assuming the distribution of call volume is uniform (a slightly different assumption than call start times are uniform), then one could calculate the standard error of the mean $\sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2000}} = 0.02236068$.  Given that the standard error of the mean is the same thing as the standard deviation of the mean, we then select the 99% point of the Gaussian, a call duration of 2.052019 minutes leaving 68.40062 hours of connection between City A and City B.

If the later, then one assumes the standard deviation would be expressed in hours, but it might also be expressed in minutes.  In either case, the solution would be trivial once you made the assumption about the standard deviation.

**EDIT**

Ah, that makes a big difference! Your source material includes the (English) text "The sum of the probabilities for occupied lines, which is higher than the number of lines, should be less than 1%. Approximate the probability function by a Gaussian distribution".  So you aren't directly meant to assume a Gaussian distribution, you are meant to assume a Gaussian distribution as an *approximation* of the binomial distribution whuber specified!

If you cf. [this resource](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATS7/BLesson3.htm) you will see that you can estimate the standard deviation of the number of connections at any given time with the formula $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$.

As @whuber observed, the probability of any given connection being used at any time is $p= \frac{2}{60*10} = 0.003333333$,.  We know the $n$ of connections is $2000$.  Thus, by substitution we estimate $\sigma = 2.577682$, in R `sqrt(2000*(2/(10*60))*(1-(2/(10*60))))`.  This value matches well a simulation of $\sigma$ in R, `sd(rbinom(200000,2000,2/(60*10)))`.

Combined with your calculated mean number of connections, it is just a matter of identifying the 99th percentile of the specified distribution.  In R, `qnorm(.99,6.6667,sqrt(2000*(2/(10*60))*(1-(2/(10*60)))))`$ = 12.66329$.  This matches well a simulation in R using `rbinom`, `quantile(rbinom(200000,2000,2/(60*10)),.99)` (although this later result is 13 because random binomial draws are discrete values not proportions).

Comment: What I search is not how long a call duration would be. I search for a number of required direct connections to handle the above-stated assumed loads with 99% confidence. In just 1% of the cases, the connections would have to be rerouted indirectly or parked in a holding stack. - It would have to be a standard deviation of the number of required phone lines at any given moment. The units would be 1 connection.

Comment: And the mean would be $6\frac{2}{3}$ connections - that many are expected to be occupied at any given time. - this simply results from filling the 10 hours with 2000 2-minute-intervals.

Comment: Russell, would you mind explaining in what sense an SD of $1$ is a "default" for this problem and in what sense that is "the best you can do"?

Comment: @whuber: Your solution involving the binomial distribution was clever.  I briefly considered something in that direction, but I didn't get all the way to a solution because I returned to kram's assertion that they were to assume a Gaussian distribution.  With a lack of data, I felt forced to make an assumption about the standard deviation of something or other.

Comment: @whuber: In regards to 1 being the 'default', that is probably a consequence of a (potentially mistaken) bias on my part.  In pedagogical circumstances the standard normal distribution has been the most frequently occurring parameterization of a Gaussian that I've encounted.  Given the pedagogical nature of the question, and its other flaws, it seamed like the best possible 'guess' as to what the author intended $\sigma$ to be.

Comment: @kram1032: If you have a 99% confidence interval of mean call duration, then you also (as I calculated above) have a 99% confidence interval for total call duration.  As you've expressed earlier it is trivial to go from total call duration to the number of connections required to process those calls, in this case 6.84 connections or more properly 7 connections.

Comment: As @whuber pointed out the question has not provided enough information to provide a solid answer using the Gaussian distribution.  As I've pointed out, the question is flawed in other regards.  If the question is creative commons somewhere, then please post a link to it so that an intrepid soul might get it fixed.

Comment: @Russell I'm certainly glad I'm not the only one to feel like the question is somewhat flawed. Here's the exercise sheet if you want to have a look. Second page is English. http://puu.sh/2gIVS - I pretty much just abridged the wording but didn't throw away any details. It's exercise 2.

Comment: Ah, I only now saw this edit. By now, we had to finish this problem and what you said is indeed the correct result. @whuber mentioned it first, but StasK's solution with a poisson distribution was almost right. - The actual answer differs only minimally.

Comment: kram1032, @StasK's suggestion solution *is* correct: you rejected it only the basis of incidental information that is irrelevant to the question itself (namely, the statistical background that is assumed of people in your class).

Comment: @whuber, yeah, I should clarify. It wasn't wrong. It merely was not what I was expected to do. Sorry. Your solution was the expected one.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to consider a Poisson distribution for the number of calls that are being currently made. You can then either take the tabulated value of the cdf (i.e., use the appropriate statistical software to compute the 99th percentile), or use the asymptotic Gaussian approximation to the Poisson.

Comment: While I agree that that would more reasonable, I'm explicitly asked to use a Gaussian. Technically, we haven't even learnt about the Poisson distribution yet. It is supposedly somehow possible to find an approximate variance for a gaussian, based on just the data I'm given.

Comment: However, if I try that, I obtain a 99.1283% confidence at 13 connections and a 99.9999% confidence for 22 connections. that at least seems reasonable. If nobody finds teh way how this is supposed to be solved, I'll go with that. Thank you very much.